# Angular Service Call

Tags: angular

I have a service call in Angular calling to the server. The problem is that, in the staging environment, the call ends abruptly on its own without waiting for the response to come back, which in turn keeps the UI blocked and the script is waiting for a response. But, when I check the Network tab, I see the response has completed at 30+ seconds, but the call stopped before that, say at about 30 seconds.

Need help in making the call wait for the response to come back no matter how much time it takes. In the local dev environment, it works all fine.

```
createNewApiObject(jsonData, listFiles, envHost, createHost = null): Promise<any> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('host', envHost)
    .set('email', this.userEmail)
    .set('refresh', 'true')
  let options;
  if (createHost != null) {
    options = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('apicreate_environment', createHost) };
  }
  const modJson = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('jsondata', modJson);
  listFiles.forEach((el, i) => {
    return formData.append(el.label, el.val);
  });

  return this.http.post(`${this.url.apiCreate}${params}`, formData, options).subscribe(data => {
    resolve(data);
  }, error => {
    reject(error);
  });
})
```

my service call invocation point:

```
this.publishService.createNewApiObject(postApi, this.modFiles, envHost, selectedHost).then(value => {
        if (value) {
          if (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)).success == true) {
            console.log('success')
          } else {
           this.blockUI.stop();
           this.isSubmitting = false;
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log("time out error");
      })
```

Comment: can you add some more details like code image etc ?

Comment: what you tried so far

Comment: code is added to the question. The weird part is that it works perfectly in the local env, only in staging, there is a problem and in the server, the error log says 'connection terminated by client'.

Comment: How long do you expect the call to take? If it takes too long it's better to send a status back immediately and poll it at a later point to know if the request is complete in the backend

Comment: the expectation is about 30s - 60s, sometimes more.